iPhone 15 Pro Max uses more iCloud data than it should (iOS 17.6.1)
I've noticed something weird recently.
When I go to Settings > Apple ID > iCloud, it says I'm using 1.9 of 5 GB. Ok, sure. That's not really weird. I've turned off Photos backing up to iCloud to save space (I'm using Google Photos instead). If I click on Manage Account Storage, there's a button that says my backups are worth 1.9 GB (in other words, the backups are the only thing getting sent to iCloud).
Here's where things get weird. If I click on that backups button mentioned above, it shows (almost) every app I have, and whether or not it back ups to iCloud.
The only app in the entire page that back ups to iCloud is Medical ID (by Apple), which is 142 KB. Last time I checked, that's nowhere near 1.9 GB. And the number keeps going up by a few MB every backup (even though the amount of data that Medical ID says is getting back upped to iCloud is always 142 KB).
The only apps that don't show up there (on that page) are:

Apple Wallet
Translate
Notes
Compass
Voice memos
Weather
Find My
Safari
Phone
Messages
Contacts
Apple TV

What's going on? How do I fix it?

sync != backup ... If you look in Settings >> AppleID >> iCloud >> iCloud Backup and click on the device name, it will show you what is being used for backups.

@MarcWilson Oh, ok thanks. All the times I wrote sync, what I really meant was backup, I just wasn't aware of the subtlety in this case.
